# How to place a document ready function inside an ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used the datepicker function on 3 other pages and all works great, but now I am trying to add it to a page that is produced based on an ajax function call showbookings.  There are currently 8 on click functions that are being reattached after it loads the dynamic content, but I can not get the datepicker to work, show, nothing. So how do you take a $(document).ready(function and place it into the ajax call? I have my input class = "datepicker1"

```
function showbookings(str, pass) {
    if (str === "") {
        document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        *********

        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "page1.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}





$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
        buttonText: 'Pick Date',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        duration: 'fast',
        onClose: function (text, inst) {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You've tagged this `jQuery`, so **use jQuery**. Stop hand-rolling your AJAX requests and just use [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). You will never produce something as robust, bug-free and cross-platform as jQuery's AJAX methods, so just use what jQuery gives you. Your entire `showbookings` method should be replace with `$.get("page1.php?q=" + str)`.

Comment: Also, [please stop using signatures in your posts and comments](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). I'm referring to the "Thanks, Kurt". Your posts are already signed with your username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how do you take a $(document).ready(function and place it into the ajax call?

You don't.  It would be meaningless in that context.  It probably wouldn't even do anything, if the `ready` event doesn't fire again for the `document` after the AJAX call.  Since all that code does is attach an event handler to that event, it doesn't actually execute the code within the handler until the event fires.

It sounds like what you *actually* want to do is initialize the date picker plugin on elements added to the DOM after an AJAX call.  You can do this by just calling the plugin initializer again:

```
$(".datepicker1").datepicker({
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
    buttonText: 'Pick Date',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    onClose: function (text, inst) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Note that this will match *all* `'.datepicker'` elements in the DOM.  Including the ones that were previously initialized.  If this causes undesirable behavior on previously initialized elements, then just restrict the selector for the plugin to include only the new elements.  From the looks of your code, that might be something like:

```
$("#txtBookings .datepicker1").datepicker({
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
    buttonText: 'Pick Date',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    onClose: function (text, inst) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Basically you'd just need to adjust the selector to specify only the elements which were added, which presumably have some common parent element.

Comment: I appreciate the response back...would I put either of your suggestions inside the function showbookings?

Comment: @stapuff: You'd do this in the response handler for the AJAX call.  Which in your code appears to be an anonymous function assigned to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: This is what I am getting as an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' booking.js:66
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: @stapuff: Then it sounds like jQuery and/or jQuery UI isn't loaded when the code executes.

Comment: Interesting....I switch the following around and it works. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @stapuff: If you were loading them in the opposite order then that would explain it.  The jQuery UI code would fail without jQuery being loaded first, the plugin(s) wouldn't be able to extend the jQuery object because it wouldn't exist yet.  You always need to load jQuery *before* loading any plugins which modify it.

Comment: I appreciate all your time and effort.  Great tip, which I didn't realize.  New to this game and just thought that they loaded and would be available.  Too much to learn for this old dog.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, it is better to use it for handling the AJAX too:

```
function showbookings(str, pass) {
    if (str === "") {
        $("#txtBookings").html("");
        return;
    }
    $.get(page1.php?q=" + str);
}
```